# How can I output only the first letter of the argument of a command?

Tags: macros

I have a command that takes a string as argument and applies some format to it. I also want that in some situations (when a counter hits a certain value) it prints only the first letter of the argument. How can I do that?

I know how to manage the counter, but not how to change the output to the first letter of the argument. I would use a regex, but I don't know how to implement it. Looking around I found [`l3regex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3regex), but it looks like it doesn't have documentation and I just can't understand the examples I found in other answers without it.

P.S.: I don't know what tags I should use for this question either. If you want to edit them you're welcome.

Comment: Maybe the `xstring`  package could give you what you want.

Comment: When processing utf8-encoded stuff by means of a traditional TeX-engine (which takes input for 8bit/byte-encoded), using the inputenc-package, then at the time of expanding macros a letter internally might be made up of serveral character-tokens. Thus detailed information is needed about what a letter / a string is in your scenario. Besides this an argument consists of a set of tokens whereof some can be expandable whose expansion at some stage yields something that can be calles "letters". Thus info is needed whether expansion needs to be taken into account also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542545/195626) generally works, but it has problems in some situations. The best thing I could make (thanks to @Schrödinger's cat comment) works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \addtocounter{mycounter}{1}
    \ifnum\value{mycounter}<3
        \textbf{#1}
    \else
        \emph{\StrChar{#1}{1}}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \mycommand{foo}
    \mycommand{bar}
    \mycommand{lorem}
    \mycommand{ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: code output]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to pull the first letter off something is to use a command like

```
\def\firstletter#1#2@{#1}
```

You use this with the word that you want to extract the first letter from followed by the `@`character: `\firstletter hello@`. When you call this `#1`, which is `h`, is printed and `#2`, which is `ello`, is discarded. The function of the `@` in this command is simply to mark the end of the string so that `#2` can slurp up everything between the first character and the end of the string. You could use anything instead of `@` here, but you should use something that should not appear in your "word" `#1#2`.

It's not entirely clear to me how you want to use this, but you talk of applying some formatting and printing the first letter based on the value of a counter. The following command fits this description:

```
\newcommand\VagueCommand[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \ifnum\value{mycounter}=5\firstletter#1@%
  \else\textbf{#1}%
  \fi%
}
```

So, `\VagueCommand` typesets its contents in bold, except on the fifth iteration when it prints the first letter of `#1`. With this in place the MWE below outputs:

[image]

Here is the full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}% define a new counter
\def\firstletter#1#2@{#1} % print first token in #1#2
\newcommand\VagueCommand[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}% increment counter
  \ifnum\value{mycounter}=5\firstletter#1@% test for mycounter=5
  \else\textbf{#1}% otherwise in bold
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

  \VagueCommand{one}
  \VagueCommand{two}
  \VagueCommand{three}
  \VagueCommand{four}
  \VagueCommand{five}
  \VagueCommand{six}
  \VagueCommand{seven}
  \VagueCommand{eight}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strictly spoken this does not pull the first letter off but does pull off the first non-delimited argument. Try, e.g., `\VagueCommand{ five}` or `\VagueCommand{{fffff}ive}` instead of `\VagueCommand{five}`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Agreed. As the comments in the code say, it is pulling off the first token.

Comment: It is not the first token. It is the first non-delimited argument. ;-)   [ `{` usually gets tokenized as an explicit character-token of category-code 1(begin group). `}` usually gets tokenized as an explicit character-token of category-code 2(end group). So the first token of the argument of `\VagueCommand` with `\VagueCommand{{fffff}ive}` would be `{`. But you get `fffff`. ]